# How to configure Spring Security for OAuth2 and JWT Authentication?

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0, jwt, google-oauth

How do I configure oauth2 to have it's own url? I need to have `/auth/google` as the url for the authentication page and publicly available. Here's what I have so far:

build.gradle

```js
plugins {
  id 'java'
  id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.1.2'
  id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.2'
}

dependencies {
  implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
  implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client'
  implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
  implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
  implementation 'io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt:0.9.1'
  implementation 'javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.2.4'
  compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
  runtimeOnly 'com.mysql:mysql-connector-j'
  annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
  testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
  testImplementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-test'
}
```

SecurityConfig.java

```js
@Configuration
@Slf4j
public class SecurityConfig {

  @Autowired
  public UserRepository userRepository;

  @Autowired
  public JwtService jwtService;

  @Bean
  public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    return http
      .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
      .cors(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
      .authorizeHttpRequests(auth - > auth
        .requestMatchers("/auth/google").authenticated()
        .requestMatchers("/api/**").authenticated()
      )
      .oauth2Login(oauth2 - > {
        oauth2.redirectionEndpoint(redirection - > {
          redirection.baseUri("/auth/google/redirect");
        });
        oauth2.successHandler(new OauthSuccessHandler(userRepository, jwtService));
        oauth2.failureHandler((request, response, exception) - > log.error("OAuth2LoginError {}", exception.getMessage()));
      })
      .sessionManagement(sess - > sess.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
      .build();
  }
}
```

I don't have `/auth/google` handled by the controller, because I did try to add this url into controller, instead of oauth2, it's render the content from the controller.

The idea is to set the `auth/google` url to be publicly available, after the sign in complete (in oauth2.successHandler function), the api will redirect user to the frontend page with jwt token sent in its request query e.g (`set-auth?accessToken=123&refreshToken=456`) after that, any api request coming from frontend that matches this url `api/**` will be handled by JWT auth handler.

How can I achieve such requirement? Any help will be much appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Your going to put the access token and refresh token in the url bar for everyone to see?

Comment: @LindaLawton-DaImTo technically yes, I can't think if there's any other way to send at/rt to the client without passing them to the url query. But it's not a plain JWT tho, the tokens will be encrypted, and afaik spring's redirect method didn't get recorded in browser history, so user can't go back to `set-auth` page. So I think this approach is still safe.

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this:

File `SecurityConfig.java`

```java
package com.example.springsocial.config;

import com.example.springsocial.security.CustomUserDetailsService;
import com.example.springsocial.security.RestAuthenticationEntryPoint;
import com.example.springsocial.security.TokenAuthenticationFilter;
import com.example.springsocial.security.oauth2.CustomOAuth2UserService;
import com.example.springsocial.security.oauth2.HttpCookieOAuth2AuthorizationRequestRepository;
import com.example.springsocial.security.oauth2.OAuth2AuthenticationFailureHandler;
import com.example.springsocial.security.oauth2.OAuth2AuthenticationSuccessHandler;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.BeanIds;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(
        securedEnabled = true,
        jsr250Enabled = true,
        prePostEnabled = true
)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private CustomUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private CustomOAuth2UserService customOAuth2UserService;

    @Autowired
    private OAuth2AuthenticationSuccessHandler oAuth2AuthenticationSuccessHandler;

    @Autowired
    private OAuth2AuthenticationFailureHandler oAuth2AuthenticationFailureHandler;

    @Autowired
    private HttpCookieOAuth2AuthorizationRequestRepository httpCookieOAuth2AuthorizationRequestRepository;

    @Bean
    public TokenAuthenticationFilter tokenAuthenticationFilter() {
        return new TokenAuthenticationFilter();
    }

    /*
      By default, Spring OAuth2 uses HttpSessionOAuth2AuthorizationRequestRepository to save
      the authorization request. But, since our service is stateless, we can't save it in
      the session. We'll save the request in a Base64 encoded cookie instead.
    */
    @Bean
    public HttpCookieOAuth2AuthorizationRequestRepository cookieAuthorizationRequestRepository() {
        return new HttpCookieOAuth2AuthorizationRequestRepository();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) throws Exception {
        authenticationManagerBuilder
                .userDetailsService(customUserDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }


    @Bean(BeanIds.AUTHENTICATION_MANAGER)
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .cors()
                    .and()
                .sessionManagement()
                    .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                    .and()
                .csrf()
                    .disable()
                .formLogin()
                    .disable()
                .httpBasic()
                    .disable()
                .exceptionHandling()
                    .authenticationEntryPoint(new RestAuthenticationEntryPoint())
                    .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/",
                        "/error",
                        "/favicon.ico",
                        "/**/*.png",
                        "/**/*.gif",
                        "/**/*.svg",
                        "/**/*.jpg",
                        "/**/*.html",
                        "/**/*.css",
                        "/**/*.js")
                        .permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/auth/**", "/oauth2/**")
                        .permitAll()
                    .anyRequest()
                        .authenticated()
                    .and()
                .oauth2Login()
                    .authorizationEndpoint()
                        .baseUri("/oauth2/authorize")
                        .authorizationRequestRepository(cookieAuthorizationRequestRepository())
                        .and()
                    .redirectionEndpoint()
                        .baseUri("/oauth2/callback/*")
                        .and()
                    .userInfoEndpoint()
                        .userService(customOAuth2UserService)
                        .and()
                    .successHandler(oAuth2AuthenticationSuccessHandler)
                    .failureHandler(oAuth2AuthenticationFailureHandler);

        // Add our custom Token based authentication filter
        http.addFilterBefore(tokenAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }

}
```

File `OAuth2AuthenticationSuccessHandler.java`

```java
package com.example.springsocial.security.oauth2;

import com.example.springsocial.config.AppProperties;
import com.example.springsocial.exception.BadRequestException;
import com.example.springsocial.security.TokenProvider;
import com.example.springsocial.util.CookieUtils;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.util.UriComponentsBuilder;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.Cookie;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.util.Optional;

import static com.example.springsocial.security.oauth2.HttpCookieOAuth2AuthorizationRequestRepository.REDIRECT_URI_PARAM_COOKIE_NAME;

@Component
public class OAuth2AuthenticationSuccessHandler extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler {

    private final TokenProvider tokenProvider;
    private final AppProperties appProperties;
    private final HttpCookieOAuth2AuthorizationRequestRepository httpCookieOAuth2AuthorizationRequestRepository;

    @Autowired
    OAuth2AuthenticationSuccessHandler(TokenProvider tokenProvider, AppProperties appProperties, HttpCookieOAuth2AuthorizationRequestRepository httpCookieOAuth2AuthorizationRequestRepository) {
        this.tokenProvider = tokenProvider;
        this.appProperties = appProperties;
        this.httpCookieOAuth2AuthorizationRequestRepository = httpCookieOAuth2AuthorizationRequestRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {
        String targetUrl = determineTargetUrl(request, response, authentication);
        if (response.isCommitted()) {
            logger.debug("Response has already been committed. Unable to redirect to " + targetUrl);
            return;
        }
        clearAuthenticationAttributes(request, response);
        getRedirectStrategy().sendRedirect(request, response, targetUrl);
    }

    protected String determineTargetUrl(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) {
        Optional<String> redirectUri = CookieUtils.getCookie(request, REDIRECT_URI_PARAM_COOKIE_NAME).map(Cookie::getValue);
        if (redirectUri.isPresent() && !isAuthorizedRedirectUri(redirectUri.get())) {
            throw new BadRequestException("Sorry! We've got an Unauthorized Redirect URI and can't proceed with the authentication");
        }
        String targetUrl = redirectUri.orElse(getDefaultTargetUrl());
        String token = tokenProvider.createToken(authentication);
        return UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString(targetUrl).queryParam("token", token).build().toUriString();
    }

    protected void clearAuthenticationAttributes(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        super.clearAuthenticationAttributes(request);
        httpCookieOAuth2AuthorizationRequestRepository.removeAuthorizationRequestCookies(request, response);
    }

    private boolean isAuthorizedRedirectUri(String uri) {
        URI clientRedirectUri = URI.create(uri);
        return appProperties.getOauth2().getAuthorizedRedirectUris()
                .stream()
                .anyMatch(authorizedRedirectUri -> {
                    // Only validate host and port. Let the clients use different paths if they want to
                    URI authorizedURI = URI.create(authorizedRedirectUri);
                    return authorizedURI.getHost().equalsIgnoreCase(clientRedirectUri.getHost())
                            && authorizedURI.getPort() == clientRedirectUri.getPort();
                });
    }

}
```

These source code is my own project. For the same project but full, you can see https://github.com/callicoder/spring-boot-react-oauth2-social-login-demo , it is very good working project for you now.

Comment: `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` is no longer available in current version of spring security I use. And also `.and()` is no longer usable. The sample you provide seems like using outdated spring version (different than mine). But I found something useful in it. I really appreciate it, so yeah +1 but not the answer I was looking for, thanks.